# how to use type application rule (T-TAPP)?

Tags: type-theory, type-checking

In the following rule,

$$\dfrac{ \Gamma \vdash t_1  : \forall X.T_{12} }
        { \Gamma \vdash t_1 \ [T_2]  : [X \mapsto T_2]T_{12} }
        \textsf{ (T-TApp)}$$

whend doing type checking, how do know what is $X$?

Also, type checking will not give you a term which has a form $[X \mapsto T_2]T_{12}$, so how to deal with that substitution?

We will have $t_1 \ [T_2]$ during type checking and $T_2$ could be any type such as $T, T \to T,\forall X.T$. How do we know $[X \mapsto T_2]$, again?

I just could not understand how to apply this rule during type checking?

Please help!

Comment: The OP is asking a lot of questions that are very closely related. Is there a better way to do this? For instance, here we have a question which is conceptually exactly the same as [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55305/how-to-use-type-application-rule-to-get-a-desired-type). It looks like the OP is reading [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) and using us to explain things that aren't clear.

Comment: Admiteddly, the other question is not from OP, but he should have looked around before asking.

Comment: @AndrejBauer "...using us to explain things that aren't clear", isn't allowed or wrong thing to do?

Comment: Well, of course, it's kind of the purpose of this site, but I am just wondering what happens when you ask a series of questions that are going to wear out the people who are answering. I am happy to answer questions about type theory, but less so when it is series of questions from the same person that come in quick succession, because then it feels like a personal service.

Comment: @AndrejBauer. I see your point. Yes, I am working on that book, solved some issues myself and too confused with others. While asking questions, I felt many people understand theory and when comes to practice quite different story. Actually, I was hoping to get answer to just one of my questions, but did not get much beyond theory. That is why I put several questions. But still, answers cleared my mind a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. there is a unification needed during type checking.

there is a condition though, $ftv(T_2) \in \Gamma_{tv}$, saying free type variables of $T2$ should be found in the set of type variables in type context.

Also, $X$ could be choose as any new new name which does not clash with existing names.

In type checking, you have $\Gamma \vdash M \quad t_2 : T$, so apply that rule.
we can write $\Gamma \vdash M: \forall X.T_1$ where $unify(T , [X \mapsto T_2]T_1$), where $unify(t1,t2)$ check if these two terms are equal.

Answer (score 5):

Type checking and the inference rules for type theory are *not an algorithm*. They do not tell you how to type check. They tell you what is *allowed* when you perform type checking.

The rule for application should be read as:

> If you can prove $\Gamma \vdash t_1 : \forall T . T_{12}$ (and we're not telling you how to do that, you'll have to figure it out) then $\Gamma \vdash t_1[T_2] : [X \to T_2]T_{12}$ for whatever $T_2$ you choose to use (and of course we do not know what it is that you're trying to do here, the choice of $T_2$ is entirely up to you).

So, the answer to your question is: *you* have to figure out how to find the value of $X$ and *you* have to worry about the subtitution. The rules are *not* meant to solve that problem. They are just *rules*, telling you what you *may* do.

The *correct* question that you should have asked is: *"How do I make an algorithm that will be able to perform type-checking automatically?"* This is an important question, and people put a lot of thought into it. I can give you an initial answer: try out all possibilities until you find one that works. But that's a lousy aglorithm and it's possible to do better.

Comment: My title is not suitable, i agree with your recommendation. is there such algorithm ? I searched internet, there is type checking algorithms for let -polymorphic, but did not see any algorithm for type checking for polymorphic lambda calculus.